# Sharing resources (json, image, text...) from a kotlin multiplatform module

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, file-sharing

A task that I thought would be pretty simple turns out a bit more complicated.
I have a .json file inside my Kotlin Multiplatform module and I would like to share it between iOS and Android (to not include it for both platforms separately). My first naive approach was to add it into a folder inside commonMain. Well that did not work (accessing the file from the two platforms results in "null", but I am not even sure that the resource was bundled with the module).
Then I checked these instructions: https://luisramos.dev/how-to-share-resources-kmm,
also did not work.
I know about this library: https://github.com/icerockdev/moko-resources but I would not want to include a library just to share a file.

Is there an easy way to say "include this folder with all its files" inside the Multiplatform module and make it accessible for all platforms? (Accessing the file can be platform dependent, but just the file should be at one place)

Comment: Could you elaborate what is wrong with solution from https://luisramos.dev/how-to-share-resources-kmm, what problems have you faced? How you try to get resources in the code. Btw I personally don't recommend share resources between iOS and Android in KMM

Comment: The issue was that calling  javaClass.classLoader!!.getResourceAsStream(name) returns "null", so the file can't be found.
If I have a json file from where data is read, I would add it only once inside the module. Also if adaptions are needed (json structure changes) I can do it all at one place. 
I would be interested to know why you think sharing resources is nt a good idea :)

Comment: Hmm, created a new project and now it works. But I would still like to know why you think it is a not a good idea to share the resource :)

Comment: Tried myself and it works for me, too. I personally  prefer avoid sharing resources in KMM shared library because Android and iOS handle resources differently and all available solutions are ugly workarounds. I believe that it is not worth it, and it's better to add resources properly in actual apps, not in shared library

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to solve and I found this solution:
I put my json file `data.json` inside the folder `/composeApp/src/commonMain/resources/`. Then I simply accessed the file using this repository (in `commonMain`):

```
class MyDataRepository {

    @OptIn(ExperimentalResourceApi::class)
    suspend fun getData(): List<MyData>? {
        return try {
            val jsonString = resource(DATA_FILE_NAME).readBytes().decodeToString()
            Json.decodeFromString<List<MyData>>(jsonString)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // Handle parsing error
            null
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val DATA_FILE_NAME = "data.json"
    }

}
```

As you can notice the function `resource()` is at the experimental stage, but it's working fine for me.